# mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysqli

I keep getting this errors and I am having problems fixing that, am not good in PHP because am still learning. I am working on a registration form and am using PHP 5.6. I have looked at other answers on older questions but I haven't succeeded.

Here is my Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
    header("Location: index.html");
}
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $fname  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
    $tphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['telephone']);
    $uemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $urole  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['role']);
    $upass  = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['upass']));
    
    $uname  = trim($uname);
    $tphone = trim($tphone);
    $email  = trim($email);
    $urole  = trim($role);
    $upass  = trim($upass);
    
    // email exist or not
    $query  = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$uemail'";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);
    
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); // if email not found then register
    
    if ($count == 0) {
        
        if (mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users(firstname,telephone,email,role,pass) VALUES('$fname','$tphone','$uemail','$urole',$upass')")) {
?>
           <script>alert('successfully registered ');</script>
            <?php
        } else {
?>
           <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
?>
           <script>alert('Sorry Email ID already taken ...');</script>
            <?php
    }
    
}
?>
```

The errors I keep getting are:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Timewise\landing\login.php on line 12
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Timewise\landing\login.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Timewise\landing\login.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Timewise\landing\login.php on line 19
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Timewise\landing\login.php on line 21

Can you please help me on this, I need to know how I should fix this practically.

Comment: DO RTM's http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php - People don't Google anymore?!

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {` Hmm, perhaps you should read the manual for `isset` too while you're at it.

Comment: that will definitely give a false positive `if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "")` - the syntax is: `if isset AND equals to`, and not `if isset equals to`

Comment: and if you plan on going live with md5, don't. A lot of water's gone under the bridge in 30+ years. Use `password_hash()`.

Comment: @Qirel so from what am gathering on the mysli_real_escape manual I should put it as this, > string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )

Comment: It may not be clear to you from reading the docs, but the `mysqli_*()` functions like `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `mysqli_query()` require as their first parameter the connection variable. Within dbconnect.php you have established a connection, probably in a variable like `$con` or `$db` or `$link`. You must pass it to those functions.

Comment: For that matter, don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, use prepared statements with bind variables

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- how is my code supposed to be I need help on that

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I have already set the db connection here is the code "<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=timewise", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    /*echo "Connected successfully";*/
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?> "

Comment: right there ^ you can't mix APIs. you need to use the same one from connecting to querying. **PDO and mysqli_ = no love.** PDO+PDO= love. mysqli_ + mysqli_ = love

Comment: @Fred-ii- so if I used PDO in my dbconnect I should not use mysqli again, instead I should do PDO all the way?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I get it now

Comment: @RyanVincent yes there is, if I got another option or meant to understand why not to use it

Comment: @RyanVincent I have read here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp and now I am persuaded never to use mysqli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *technically* answer this, both of these functions require a db connection be passed and as the first parameter, as per the manuals:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Then in comments you state that you are using PDO to connect with.

Those different MySQL APIs do not intermix. You need to use the same one from connecting to querying. Therefore, if you want to continue to use a PDO connection, you will need to use the PDO functions to query with and not `mysqli_*`.

- Start with the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php it's all in there.

And for PDO prepared statements:

- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Check for errors also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php (PDO)
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php (PHP)

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you are attemtpting to store passwords MD5. This is not recommended as it is no longer considered safe to use as a password storing function.

- If you are intending on going LIVE with this, ***don't.***

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or crypt, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

---

As I also stated:

`if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "")` will give you a false positive.

The syntax is: `if isset AND equals to`, and not `if isset equals to` which is what it is presently being interpreted as.

Use:

`if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != "")`

In regards to your POST arrays.

Make sure the HTML form you are using does use a POST method and that all elements hold their respective name attributes.

I.e.: `<input type="text" name="fullname">` etc.

Note that `name="fullname"` and `name="FullName"` are two different animals.

- Those are case-sensitive.

It is also suggested to add `exit;` after each header, otherwise your code may want to continue to execute.

```
header("Location: index.html");
exit;
```